# How to do a merge commit

Tags: git

In my application I have 2 branches: `x` and `dev`. I created an pull request from x. 
Then I had some conflicts trying to merge. I solved the conflicts in the next way: I accessed dev branch and I ran `git merge x`. After fixing the conflicts, I ran `git add .` , `git commit -m`.

Now should I do `git push origin dev`?

If I do this, will I see my last commit as a merge commit or as a simple  commit in dev branch?

Answer (score 0):

> [...] will I see my last commit as a merge commit or as a simple commit in
>   dev branch?

You'll see both a merge commit and your last commit.

Your `dev` branch will have a merge commit, and the commit made on your branch `x` will be reachable. See schematically here : (where `D` is the merge commit)

```
 A---B-------D <<< dev
      \     /
       \---C <<< x
```

Comment: so it is correct to run `git push origin dev` from dev branch, after solving conflicts?

Comment: Yes, provided the branch is not protected against pushes. Some repos are configured like that to force devs to use pull requests and control what's merged in.